# Add a conditional line to existing script

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, script

I've got this script from an earlier question and answer ([specific resize layer action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/58812/64765)) Many thanks to SQW!

```
(function (){
    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
    var bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;  
    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
    var newSize = (100 / width) * 550; 
    activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.BOTTOMLEFT);
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;  
})();
```

However, is it possible for the script to only run when the layer that needs to be resized is, for example, greater than 550px? I am a complete noob when it comes to scripting, and I've tried adding in an "if" function but I just don't understand how it works...

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't graphic design related.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SuperMerlin over at the adobe forums, he has given me the answer.

```
(function (){ 
    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;   
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS; 
    var bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;   
    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value; 
    if(width > 550){
        var newSize = (100 / width) * 550;   
        activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.BOTTOMLEFT); 
    }
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;
})();
```