# Apply a script to all selected layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, script, scale

I have a script modified from here:
[specific resize layer action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58812/specific-resize-layer-action/65235#65235?newreg=410dfe60f332469a80e630253658e823)

Which will resize a selected layer to fit within 300px
(I tweaked it to check if width or height are bigger, and scale accordingly)

Is there a way to make this script apply to all selected layers?

```
(function (){
    var targetSize = 300
    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  
    var bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds; 
    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
    var height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;
    if(width>height){
        var newSize = (100 / width) * targetSize;  
    }else{
        var newSize = (100 / height) * targetSize; 
    }
    activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;  
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Firstly you need to find a way of telling Photoshop what layers are currently selected. There's no built in method for this, so you have to put them in a group, add them to an array and then put everything back to normal.

Then it's just a matter of looping over that little list and performing your function above. I've renamed it to `do_that_thing()`

So the whole thing looks like this:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF

var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  

var mySelection = [];
get_selected_layers(); // selected layers
// alert(selected_layers);

// loop over the selected layers
for (var i=0; i < mySelection.length; i++)
{
  do_that_thing();
}

//Reset units
app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;  

// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL

//functions here:

function do_that_thing()
{
  var targetSize = 300;
  var bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds; 
  var width  = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
  var height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;

  if(width > height)
  {
    var newSize = (100 / width) * targetSize;  
  }
  else
  {
    var newSize = (100 / height) * targetSize; 
  }

  activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
}


function get_selected_layers()
{
  // taken from
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255364/

  var resultLayers = [];
  try
  {
    // create a temp group
    var idGrp = stringIDToTypeID( "groupLayersEvent" );
    var descGrp = new ActionDescriptor();
    var refGrp = new ActionReference();
    refGrp.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ),charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ),charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ));
    descGrp.putReference(charIDToTypeID( "null" ), refGrp );
    executeAction( idGrp, descGrp, DialogModes.NO );

    for (var ix=0; ix < app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers.length; ix++)
      {
        resultLayers.push(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers[ix]);
        mySelection.push(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers[ix]);
      }

    // get rid of the temp group
    // delete history state
    // =======================================================
    var idDlt = charIDToTypeID( "Dlt " );
    var desc103 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref27 = new ActionReference();
    var idHstS = charIDToTypeID( "HstS" );
    var idCrnH = charIDToTypeID( "CrnH" );
    ref27.putProperty( idHstS, idCrnH );
    desc103.putReference( idnull, ref27 );
    executeAction( idDlt, desc103, DialogModes.NO );

  } 
  catch 
  (eeek)
  {
    alert("Something went wrong")
  };

  return resultLayers;
}
```